# Adding guests to the event through Google Apps Script without notification

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-calendar-api

I try to create a Google event series using google apps script. And i wonder how i can add guests to the event without sending notification to them.

I tried a lot of thing and nothing worked. The code works and creates event and adds guests but I can't figure out how not to send notifications to the guests about them being added. My last version :

```
var event = calendar.createAllDayEventSeries( 
    title, 
    date, 
    CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addYearlyRule(), 
    { guests:  hiringManagerEmail, sendInvites: false } 
);
```

Comment: A complete [mcve] might be helpful or perhaps you can report it as an issue: - [List of Issues](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/566222)